# Git Submodule Update - Permission denied

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git repository A that contains a submodule B. When I execute `git submodule update --init --recursive` in repository A to update the submodule, I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error. The ssh key is correctly added to the remote (gitlab) and I can clone both repositories independently via ssh. Cloning B outside of A works. 
Repository B is in the same group as repository A (on gitlab).

I tried the following:

- Setting an absolute reference in the `.gitmodules`
- Changing the reference in `.gitmodules` to http
- Making a clean clone of A
- Adding a fresh ssh key (with and without passphrase)
- Cloning repository A with option `--recursive`

How can I solve the problem?

The `.gitmodules` contains the following content:

```
[submodule "B"]
    path = path_to_B
    url= ../B.git
```

The complete error message:

```
Cloning into '{path_to_B}'...
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of '{git@.../B.git}' into submodule path '{path_to_B}' failed
Failed to clone '{path_to_B}'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '{path_to_B}'...
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of '{git@.../B.git}' into submodule path '{path_to_B}' failed
Failed to clone '{path_to_B}' a second time, aborting
```

Comment: Can you try to clone B, outside of A?

Comment: Cloning B outside of A works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Cloning repository B manually into the location of the submodule solved the issue. After that, updating worked again.